# SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity limitation violation: 1062 'mail@mail.com' duplicate entry for 'users_email_unique' key

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication, eloquent

I have a registration form. When the email is registered in the database it gets an error message

> ```
> SQLSTATE [23000]: Violation of integrity restrictions: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mail@mail.com' for 'users_email_unique' key
> ```

I want to avoid that mistake and instead get a warning like "registered email" or something similar. Any help is appreciated. This is my code.

> controller/auth/registercontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace VMS\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use VMS\User;
use VMS\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|min:4',
        'id_level' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|min:4|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
        'confirm' => 'required|same:password',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
}
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \VMS\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'id_level' => $data['id_level'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $id_level = $request->input('id_level');
    $email        = $request->input('email');
    $password     = $request->input('password');
$user = User::create([
    'name'      => $name,
    'id_level'      => $id_level,
    'email'     => $email,
    'password'  => Hash::make($password)
]);

if($user) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Register Berhasil!'
    ], 201);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Register Gagal!'
    ], 400);
}

}
}
```

> User.php (Model)

```
<?php

namespace VMS;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'id_level', 'email', 'password', 
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
protected $connection = 'vms_db';
}
```

> register.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>SI-BeLa</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>
<div id="app">
    <main class="py-4">
        <div class="container" style="margin: 0; min-width: 100%">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: ; padding-right: 20px;">
                    @guest
                        <a class="logo" href="{{ url('/') }}">{{ __('SI-BeLa') }}</a>
                    @endguest
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <h2 class="title">
                <br><br>
                <div style="text-align: center;">REGISTER
                @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                @endif
                    <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="cont_form_sign_up text-center">
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control2" placeholder="Nama" id="name" name="name" pattern=".{4,}" required="required" title="Paling sedikit 4 karakter">
                            <p style="font-size:12px; color:red; text-align:left; padding-left: 17%;" >* Nama paling sedikit 4 Karakter</p>
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control2" value="9" id="id_level" name="id_level">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control2" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" name="email" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+">
                            <p style="font-size:12px; color:red; text-align:left; padding-left: 17%;" >* Email harus aktif & Pastikan email belum terdaftar di SIBeLa</p>
                            <input type="password" id="pw1" name="password" class="form-control2" placeholder="Password"
                                required="required" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
                            <p style="font-size:12px; color:red; text-align:left; padding-left: 17%;" >* Password paling sedikit 8 karakter serta mengandung angka, huruf kecil dan besar</p>
                            <input type="password" id="pw2" name="confirm" class="form-control2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <center>
                                    {!! NoCaptcha::renderJs() !!}
                                    {!! NoCaptcha::display() !!}
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</span>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-linkk" href="/loginpl">
                                {{ __('Kembali ke login') }}
                            </a>
                            <br>
                            <button class="button gd-btn btn-2 btn-primaryy" onclick="cambiar_sign_up()"><strong>REGISTER</strong> </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
                
</main>
```

[image]

How do I make a notification alert if the email is registered?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this. Remove `unique:users` from validation

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|min:4',
    'id_level' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|min:4|email',
    'password' => 'required',
    'confirm' => 'required|same:password',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use laravel validation in your controller for validate request parameters.

first add this use top of your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

then in your registercontroller define this method

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|max:10',
            'name' => 'nullable|string|max:50',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $response = $validator->errors();
            session()->flash('flash_error', $response);
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        /**
         * create new user
         */
        try {


            /**
             * new user
             */
            User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new HttpException(500, $e->getMessage());
        }

        session()->flash('flash_success', 'you are registered.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

by default email field in laravel is unique and for validate it we use this exception :

```
unique:users
```

`users` is table name.

to learn more about laravel validation

see this link
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

to access validation errors in view file
we pass errors flash session with name `flash_error`
you can show it for example like this:

```
@if(session()->has('flash_error'))
    <ul>
         @foreach(session()->get('flash_error') as $error)
            <li>{{ session()->get('flash_error') }}</li>
         @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

and show success message with bootstrap like this:

```
@if(session()->has('flash_success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
       {{ session()->get('flash_success') }}
    </div>   
@endif
```